# Lookup column is not showing newly added items in lookup list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Newly added items are now coming in master list dropdown in sharepoint online. I have dropdown named Hospitals which is a lookup column from Hospital list. Now I have added new items in lookup/child but these are not appearing in master list dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

This is a delay problem. You added an item to the source list, but the target list (lookup column) is not updated immediately. Please refresh the page and wait for a few minutes for it to be displayed automatically.

[image]

Comment: We are facing this issue in one of our site which is converted to classic for some reason. Newly added item is not showing in target list.

Comment: Only this one site collection has encountered this problem, right? You try to delete the newly created item before converting to classic, will this problem occur after re-creation?

Comment: you are right I also tested on another list but same thing is happening that newly created items are not showing in lookup dropdown, do you know this issue and forward me to some solution, thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you to try another account.

Comment: As per to below link, I think it is a known bug but still Microsoft is not able to fix this issue.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/none-option-does-not-show-in-modern-lookup-column/m-p/240507